# Wanted to call action of the linking controller in ember js?

Tags: ember.js, controller

```
{{#link-to "login"}}<span {{action 'loginfunc'}}>Login</span>{{/link-to}}
```

the above code  is in my ember signup template , i have linked to login template.
I wanted to call my 'loginfunc' in my login controller, but the complier is checking 'loginfunc' inside the sign up controller, can you please tell me why, i'm a beginner.  someone guide me with this.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO as well as the Ember community.

By default, in Ember, the structure for a page (say, `signup`) would be like,

- **signup template**: UI markup layout
- **signup route file**: Handles the routing and data fetching part
- **signup controller file**: Handles the data processing and act as backing class

The things you refer to in a template will usually be looked up in the backing "controller" file. Hence, if you refer to an `action` in the `signup` template will be looked up in the `signup` controller.

If you want to call a method in `login` controller after transitioning to `login` route, try invoking it inside one of the dedicated hooks/events such as [`setupController`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.25/classes/Route/methods/setupController?anchor=setupController), [`activate`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.25/classes/Route/methods/activate?anchor=activate) etc., inside the `login` route file.